# How to make appeared popover on mat-grid

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I made grid-layout using material grid on Angular.Added popover on a link.But when I click the link,popover can't get appeared completely.I know its because strict grid divs.But I thought that would be solved by changing z-index.I did it but still same problem is going on.Somehow it should be in front of all grid divs.But I don't know how can I do that?

Here demo below what I tried included my grid and popover

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqsbi-iwgfut?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.css

Comment: adding `overflow:unset` to already written styles for `mat-grid-tile` in `grid-list-overview-example.css` should work

Answer (score 4):

Your popover is opening inside `mat-grid-tile` which has css applied `overflow:hidden` which cause popover to hide so Set `overflow: unset` on `mat-grid-tile`  should fix you problem so add some class to container grid tile

```
<mat-grid-tile colspan="2" rowspan="1" class="o-unset">
        <li style="text-align: center" class="list-unstyled">
            <a href="javascript:;" role="button" [ngbPopover]="popStatus" popoverClass="my-custom-class">
        My Link
        </a>                                                              
     </li> 
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

then in your component css

```
 .o-unset{
   overflow: unset;
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqsbi-r6grvn)

Comment: adding `overflow:unset` to already written styles for `mat-grid-tile` in `grid-list-overview-example.css` should work

Comment: Thanks very much man!But problem is when user refreshes this page that doesn't work.It only works if user come to this component from home component

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek can you please create a stackblitz to reproduce your problem.Bcs i reload the demo stackblitz it's working

Comment: I haven't updated my stackblitz yet.After I add,I'll share here

Comment: @jitender https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58231715/how-to-override-mat-grid-tile-css you can go to this link I explained my problem with more details