# How to override .mat-grid-tile css

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have popover inside mat-grid-tile and its not being opened because of `overflow:hidden`.To override it,I added a css class and changed the attribute as `overflow:unset` and that works fine.But problem is that when page is getting reloaded,this unset is being override by .mat-grid-tile css class and I don't know why this happens.I have to override it as you can see on my images.How can I do that?

A demonstration of my app on stackblitz:(Here this problem never occurs,I shared this to show you my layout design)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsqsbi-z5dyus?file=app/grid-list-overview-example.html

When page refreshed

[image]

After I changed it manually in the console(it look like this whether page refresh or not)

[image]

Comment: you could override the .mat-class in your component styles by adding /deep/ annotation before css selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `!important` should fix your problem so use

```
.o-unset{
overflow: unset !important;
}
```

instead of

```
 .o-unset{
overflow: unset;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much man!I've been working on this to solve for long time.You;'re great!

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek glad it help